# Are there cases where global keyword is necessary in python?

Tags: python, global-variables, global

I want to know if there are some cases where declaring global keyword is necessary in python.

Comment: This is a rather general question for which you can find the answer easily in the official Python documentation. E.g. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are some cases where `global` is neccessary.
Have a look at this code, which will work fine:

```
i = 42 # this is a global var

def f():
    print(i)
```

But what if you would like to edit `i` (which is a global variable).
If you do this, you get an error:

```
i = 42 # this is a global var

def f():
    i += 1 # this will not work
    print(i)
```

We can only access `i`. If python compiles the function to bytecode it detects an assignment to a variable and it assumes it is a local variable. But this is not the case here (it is a global variable). Therefore if we also want to modify the global var `i` we must use the `global` keyword.

```
i = 42 # this is a global var

def f():
    global i
    i += 1 # this will change the global var without error
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have shared resources and want to make changes in global one.

```
a = 0

def add_five():
    global a
    a += 5

def remove_two():
    global a
    a -= 2

add_five() # a = 5
add_five() # a = 10
add_five() # a = 15
remove_two() # a = 13
```